# Trigger change type only once when observing Firestore listeners

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, listener, snapshot

There is a popout triggered based on a user marking an action as complete. But if the user checks off many items and doesn’t refresh the page, all of the previous popouts continue to pop up and they have to x out of each one of them each time.

Not sure why this is, and I have an unsubscribe.

```html
    async checkProgress(){
        debugger
      if (this.Origin == 'SGBA') {
       if (this.data?.action==="update" && this.status == 'Complete') {
        //Gets modified document data to pass into progress popout component
        let newData;
        let q = await this.busiAssessmentService.readOverallData2(this.UID);
        const unsubscribe = await onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
       let  changes = snapshot.docChanges()
       console.log(changes.length)
       changes.forEach((change) => { 
            console.log(change.type)
            console.log("change.type")
          if (change.type === "modified") {
              newData = change.doc.data();
              console.log("Modified doc: ", change.doc.data());
               this.openBox(newData, this.inputSource, this.Category)
              return newData;
              }
            });
          },(error) => {
              console.log(error)
           });
           if (newData !== undefined){
            unsubscribe();
           }
      }
     }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using `ChangeDetection.OnPush` on your component?

Comment: Yes, I took it out and tested it without it but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Instead of unsubscribing `onSnapshot` on undefined `newData` value. Trigger unsubscribe after `this.openBox`. Here's an example [snippet](https://codefile.io/f/taMsHwZNppWiVM8WZXEI), let me know if it worked you or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were unsubscribing onSnapshot unsubscription at wrong place instead of unsubscribing at the end unsubscribe just after `this.openBox(newData, this.inputSource, this.Category);` line.

Updated code :

```
async checkProgress(){
  if (this.Origin == 'SGBA') {
    if (this.data?.action==="update" && this.status == 'Complete') {
      //Gets modified document data to pass into openBox
      let newData;
      let q = await this.busiAssessmentService.readOverallData2(this.UID);
      const unsubscribe = await onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
        let changes = snapshot.docChanges();
        console.log(changes.length);
        changes.forEach((change) => { 
          console.log(change.type);
          console.log("change.type");
          if (change.type === "modified") {
            newData = change.doc.data();
            console.log("Modified doc: ", change.doc.data());
            this.openBox(newData, this.inputSource, this.Category);
            unsubscribe(); // unsubscribe from the listener after the first popout
          }
        });
      }, (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    }
  }
}
```